# Can I share a Virtual Machine between Ubuntu and Windows 7?

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox

I have a Ubuntu Server virtual machine configured on Windows 7 which has a NAT and Host-Only network adapter configured. I have ports forwarded on the NAT connection in order for my host (W7) to access services on the VM guest.

Is there a way to use the same virtual machine from an Ubuntu host (dual boot with W7)? I tried already and it throws an error saying that the VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter does not exist presumably because this adapter is Windows specific.

There is no particular reason I have both NAT and Host-Only adapters configured, except that they work. Maybe there's a better solution?

Comment: You simply need to add/reconfigure the Host-Only networking on the Linux host - it is not a Windows specific capability. See the VirtualBox manual page on [Host-Only Networking](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly)

Comment: Without being able right now to reboot into Ubuntu and try anything, I have to say I did try to reconfigure the HO networking. It gave me 'vboxhost0' (or similar, can't remember exactly) as a Host-Only network which I then set the machine network to use instead of the 'VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter'. Started the machine, and I still got the error, almost like my changing the setting did not change anything